# Why there is a difference in BottomAppBar height on android and ios with flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have implemented a bottom app bar in a flutter app, but the height in both the devices are different and even the margin also.

main.dart

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
    icon: Icon(
        Icons.fiber_manual_record,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, probably cause by screen resolution and rendering method. you should not worry that they are not 1 to 1 the same :)

Comment: But the bottom margins are different according to the device, the top margins are same